# How to change text of chart annotation

Tags: charts, annotations, vb.net-2010

I would like to change the text of my `TextAnnotation` in a chart. However, I can't find the `.Text` property in `chart.Annotations("annoRent")` .I know it is because I haven't specified it is a `TextAnnotation`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can cast it as `TextAnnotaion` then use `Text` property as usual:

```
((TextAnnotation)chart.Annotations("annoRent")).Text = "your text";
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my case work only by count, not by name: ((TextAnnotation)tempchart.Annotations[0]).Text = "your text";

Answer (score 1):

```
' Create a callout annotation
        Dim annotationCallout As New CalloutAnnotation()

        ' Setup visual attributes
        annotationCallout.AnchorDataPoint = Chart11.Series(0).Points(critvalpoint) ' this is the data point in the series
        annotationCallout.AnchorX = 'this is an x-value in chart
        annotationCallout.AnchorY = 'this is a y-value in chart
        annotationCallout.Text = "Hello World"
        annotationCallout.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0)
        annotationCallout.ClipToChartArea = "Default"

        ' Prevent moving or selecting
        annotationCallout.AllowMoving = False
        annotationCallout.AllowAnchorMoving = False
        annotationCallout.AllowSelecting = False

        ' Add the annotation to the collection
        Chart1.Annotations.Add(annotationCallout)

        ' Create a rectangle annotation
        Dim annotationRectangle As New RectangleAnnotation()

        ' Setup visual attributes
        annotationRectangle.Text = "Attached to" + ControlChars.Lf + "Chart Picture"
        annotationRectangle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0)
        annotationRectangle.AnchorX = 30
        annotationRectangle.AnchorY = 25

        ' Prevent moving or selecting
        annotationRectangle.AllowMoving = False
        annotationRectangle.AllowAnchorMoving = False
        annotationRectangle.AllowSelecting = False

        ' Add the annotation to the collection
        Chart1.Annotations.Add(annotationRectangle)
```